# JavaScript and iframes: dangerous for my website?

Tags: javascript, iframe, preview

In order to see a live preview of another website that users link to on my website, I'm using iframes.

However, this is probably not the best solution, as a website is loaded directly into mine, with every JavaScript element etc that is on the linked page.

My question: how dangerous is it to do such a thing? What is the worst case scenario that could happen? Could a linked site just by using JavaScript (or other technologies) do any serious harm to my site or my user's data?

---

And then, the second part of my question is, of course, about the website preview.
All I found so far are scripts that contain more than one php and js file in order to load a website preview picture.

Isn't there an easier way to do this? What do you suggest?

Comment: If the websites are on different domains, they won't be able to directly manipulate/talk to each other. The one option is with `window.postMessage` (a newer technology not available in all browsers), but then it's up to you to filter out messages by URL. If you're not using `window.postMessage`, then you shouldn't worry.

Comment: Is it not possible for any iframed website to shoot a thousand alert windows, making it impossible to use my website? Or is this somehow prevented by the iframe?

Comment: I guess, technically yes. But in that case, modern browsers allow the user to prevent multiple alerts from happening

Comment: Okay. So you would say it is a legit method to preview a linked website?

Comment: I would. But that's me. If it is in another domain, it cannot access your JavaScript code/variables, your HTML, any cookies for your site, and similar things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how dangerous is it to do such a thing?

Some websites do not like to be embedded using frames. Such websites can possibly take over the full browser by ensuring it is loaded in the topmost window. Aside from that, as long as your website and the website you are loading aren't from the same domain, they won't be able to access your cookies, DOM etc. So its pretty safe in that respect.

> about the website preview

There aren't many fool proof mechanisms other than generating the preview image server side - as I believe the scripts you've seen do.